# Cannot create GCP VM, public images are empty

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

When attempting to create a new GCP VM on a new account, the list of public images is empty. If I try to launch an image from the public marketplace, the boot device will not be attached.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: Boot Disk screen showing no images]

Comment: what happens when you open cloud shell (right upper corner square with ">" sign) and type in " gcloud compute images list " without "

Comment: I get a list of images

Comment: @KeithRockhold What’s the Region and Zone that you selected for your new VM Instance? On the other hand, as you mentioned that you are using a New Account in GCP, did you create a New Project inside this New Account before trying to create a new VM Instance? And, finally, what’s the New Account’s role?

Comment: Make sure the identity that you logged into the Google Cloud Console GUI has **Compute Image User** aka roles/compute.imageUser. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.imageUser

Answer (score 1):

1. open cloud shell as per my comment (right upper corner square with ">" sign)

---

2. list images using
   `gcloud compute images list`

Output will look like this:
[image]

---

3. try to create your VM with desired image via opened cloud shell using for example the following

`gcloud compute instances create test --image-family ubuntu-1804-lts --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud`

Output should look something like this:
[image]

If so, you will find your instance running under compute engine.

---

PS.

Dont forget to turn these VMs off when you are done.

If you want to select another image make sure to use image project and image family from output from step 2.

Either way at least this should give you some errors to resolve

Comment: Thank you, this was great advice which got me to my solution

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was caused by the security group in my organization which set a public image constraint and neglected to ensure my team was aware of it.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/restricting-image-access

Comment: I see constraints catch people by surprise sometimes. If you create a compute instance using the example in @yev's answer, what is the error message with the constraint enabled?

Comment: I don't have it on me, but it was clear that I did not have access due to violation of  constraints/compute.trustedImageProjects